# Specify the time offset with an NSDateFormatter (-0500)

Tags: ios, cocoa, time, nsdateformatter, offset

I have some date strings similar to these:

```
2013-01-25 00:00:00 -0500
2013-01-22 00:00:00 -0700
2013-01-26 00:00:00 -0200
```

I want to use an `NSDateFormatter` to create an `NSDate` using these kinds of strings. I know how to use a formatter to get the first part of the date (`2013-01-25 00:00:00`), but I don't know how to specify the offset part (`-0500`, `-0200`, etc). Here's the code to get the start of the date string:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss"];
NSString *dateString = @"2013-01-25 00:00:00"; // <-------- Truncated ----
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", date);
```

How can I get it working with the `-0500` part? I tried `SSSZ`, but it didn't work (gave a `null` date).

Comment: Exactly you wanna "Date: 2013-01-25 00:00:00 -0500". Am i right ?

Comment: @DharmbirChoudhary I added some more examples of the format the date comes in.

Comment: Am asking you wanna your output like this    "Date: 2013-01-25 00:00:00 -0500". Am i right ?

Comment: @DharmbirChoudhary No, I'm going in the opposite direction. I already have a formatted string, I want to create an `NSDate` from it.

Comment: Please tell me what you wanna "Date : ......"

Comment: You wanna only this string  "2013-01-25 00:00:00" in NSDate. ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss ZZZ"];
NSString *dateString = @"2013-01-25 00:00:00 -0500";
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", date);
```

I get:

> Date: 2013-01-25 05:00:00 +0000

As a side note, here is the standard for all date formats: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-4.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: Works great, thank you. Does the `ZZZ` work with any time zone information?

Comment: Glad to help.  Here is the complete standard for date formatting options for your reference: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-4.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: why this is always +000

Comment: @Jitendra it is always +0000 because it adjusts the offset time provided in dateString to GMT, which is +0000. Hence why 00:00:00 is now 05:00:00, it added 5 hours because the time provided was 5 hours behind GMT.